# What is the difference between using Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy and rel="noopener noreferrer"?

Tags: websecurity, window.opener, cross-origin-opener-policy

The [Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy) header seems to be quite similar to what the `rel="noopener noreferrer"` attribute does when opening document in a new tab (`target="_blank"`).

When should I use which one? It seems the COOP header is applicable when I link between origins while the `rel="noopener noreferrer"` attribute (on anchor tags) seems to work on the same origin as well.

The COOP header also doesn't work over HTTP.

Should I use both? They seem to be quite complimentary.

I am a bit confused here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I understand:

COOP will allow you to block access to your window object if someone opens your window from their window, while noreferrer / noopener is for when you don't want the windows that you open as child, to have access to your window object.

- COOP blocks window access when you window is opened as child
- noreferrer / noopener blocks window access when your window is the parent